# CSS HTML animation with input

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm developing a website and wanted to put an animated search on it ...
I really enjoyed this animation: `https://videohive.net/item/search-logo-reveal/19279469?s_rank=149`
And I wonder if there's any way I can do it.
My code here: `https://jsfiddle.net/4txmdqhx/`
With some optimization errors, because I'm still starting.

Thanks!

Comment: please add your code

Comment: My code is on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4txmdqhx/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.form-fild input,.form-fild textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});

$('.form-fild input,.form-fild textarea').blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
<style>
.open {
  color:red;   
}
.form-fild {
 position: relative;
 margin: 30px 0;
}
.form-fild label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 10px;
 padding:5px;
}

.form-fild.open label {
 top: -25px;
 left: 10px;
 /*background: #ffffff;*/
}
.form-fild input[type="text"] {
 padding-left: 80px;
}
.form-fild textarea {
 padding-left: 80px;
}
.form-fild.open textarea, 
.form-fild.open input[type="text"] {
 padding-left: 10px;
}
textarea,
input[type="text"] {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
textarea,
input,
.form-fild.open label,
.form-fild label {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <form>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Email :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Number :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Message :</label>
            <textarea cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
.searchbar{
width: 200px;
height: 24px;
animation-name: searchbar;
animation-duration: 5s;
}   
@keyframes searchbar{
0%{width: 0px;}
20%{width: 40px;}
40%{width: 80px;}
60%{width: 120px;}
80%{width: 160px;}
100%{width: 200px;}
 }
```

You can adjust width according to your needs aswell as height and animation-duration.

```
<form>     
<input   class="searchbar" 
type="text" value="enter text here">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But i need border animations... Can you help me? An line surrounding the input.

Comment: Like that: [Preview](https://0.s3.envato.com/h264-video-previews/60f11f32-6012-4467-950e-d35fddd155ee/19279469.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , included border you can change color according to you

```
.searchbar{
width: 200px;
height: 24px;
animation-name: searchbar;
animation-duration: 5s;
border: 2px solid;
}   
@keyframes searchbar{
0%{width: 0px;
border-top-color: green;}
20%{width: 40px;
 border-right-color: red;}
40%{width: 80px; 
border-bottom-color: gold;}
60%{width: 120px; 
border-left-color: blue;}
80%{width: 160px; 
 border-top-color: pink;}
100%{width: 200px;}
 }
```

And this,

```
<input   class="searchbar" 
type="text" value="enter text here">
</form>
```